# Python : JSON-RPC 32700 error?

Tags: python, json, json-rpc, xbmc

I'm sending the following request to XBMC to add a file to a playlist:

```
req2 = '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "Playlist.Add", "params":{"playlistid":1, "item" :{ "file" : "' + path + '"}}, "id" : "addToPlaylist"}'

connection.request('POST', '/jsonrpc', req2)

response = self.connection.getresponse()
if response.status == httplib.OK:
    print response.read()
```

But I get the 32700 error, which I know means that the JSON is invalid.
But I know my path is good, and the connection to XBMC is ok too.
Do you have any idea why it doesn't work ? given that I made this code work localy on another computer...

Thanks in advance !
Robin